# how to implement Excel vlookup on Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x, excel

I have a dataset A and dataset B, both data has a column in common which is the ID, i want to check if dataset A ID values can be found in dataset B ID values. Also get the records of dataset B that have the same value with dataset A. I can do this on excel using vlookup, but I want to automate the process using python.

NOTE:
1. dataset B has 10020 rows while dataset A has 2039 rows.
2. The ID column is numeric.

Thanks.

Comment: If the ID column is duplicated in B but unique in A, I think it is ok, right? because you want to get all rows in B that belong to the same row in A.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will want to load your data in two pandas data frames (if you haven't already)
2. Next you will need to use [dataframe.join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

*Note: You might want to think about the mode (inner, outer, left or right)*

Comment: Join is not working because I have duplicates in the column that is common to dataset A and B.

Comment: Checking: in both datasets there is a column id, and in neither of which it is unique?

Comment: Do you have duplication in the ID column in both tables?